# CRM 2011 Form Adding Tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm-2011

I am applying ToolTip on some fields in the CRM form.

My ToolTip text is like:

"**Please assign To Sales Rep's**"

It works fine but the part of string **Rep's** shows as **Rep?s**

It means the special character between "Rep" and "s" is not supported.

Am i wrong? or there is a way out for this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the entity code described at [HTML Codes - Characters and symbols](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm).

For `'` the symbol is `&#39;`

Also see [IMPLEMENTING TOOLTIPS FOR MICROSOFT DYNAMICS CRM 2011](http://www.madronasg.com/blog/implementing-tooltips-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011#.UjBNZdJkM2l), which verifies this approach

Comment: I could not try this..may be correct..but if you will use this "\u2032" instead of [']. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

Replacing **\u2032** instead of **'** worked well...:)

Thankyou all.

Thanks